# creating a UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a file, called Map:

```
@interface Map : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate> {
    IBOutlet MKMapView *map;
}
```

In interfaceBuider Map starts when the tab is clicked:

[image]

Map opens a UITableViewController when clicking and this UITableView opens another UITableViewController.

So what I want now is in the last UITableViewController, when back button is pressed, back to map. I never change the tab, I'm always at "Plano"

so, in Navigation.m I have:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization

}
return self;
}
```

And in my secondUITableView.m:

```
Navigation *aMap = [[Navigation alloc]initWithNibName:@"Map" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:aMap animated:YES];
```

And what the error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist.'
```

How can I do this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** :

For back - root

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

For back

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: This just back one view, I need to back two